# Example of discrete subspace on a plane which has a closure of continuum?

Tags: general-topology, discrete-geometry

I thought that I could take all points with rational coordinates, but this space is not discrete

Comment: @bangs No, it doesn't have to be closed. For instance, $\left\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\, \frac1x\in\Bbb N\right\}$ is discrete and not closed.

Comment: You are correct. I am familiar with a different standard definition of discrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $$D_n=\{(k/2^n, 1/n)\in \mathbb{R}^2: k\in \mathbb{Z}\}.$$  Let $D=\cup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$. Then $D$ is discrete. To see this, note that if $x\in D_n$, then no other point of $D$ is closer than $\min\{2^{-n}, \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\}$ to $x$.

But the closure of $D$ contains the entire $x$-axis.

Comment: It seems that $D_n$, and hence $D$, is a collection of intervals.  What is meant by the distance between one interval and another?  Or, the closure of a set of intervals?

Comment: Each $D_n$ and $D$ is a subset of the plane. Their members are ordered pairs.

Comment: Oh, you mean $D_n=\{(k/2, 1/n) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: Yes. The OP asked for a subset of the plane, so I was a little sloppy. I have edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

In [this note](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/26.pdf) a classic fact is shown that in a metric space the boundary of an open set is the closure of a discrete set. So e.g. the circle in the plane, being the boundary of the open unit disk, is such a set.